# Prototype JS Framework - Calling a function when updates occur with a periodic updater

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

How do I call a function on every update? Below is what I tried. It doesn't work. The function itself works fine when I execute it alone.

```
new Ajax.PeriodicalUpdater('chatMessages', 'chat/receive_chat',
        {
                method: 'post',
                parameters: {lId: latestId},
                insertion: Insertion.Bottom,
                frequency: 2,
                decay: 2,
                Onsuccess: val = function(){$('chatMessages').scrollTop = $('chatMessages').scrollHeight;}
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this as simple as a case-sensitivity issue?

You have:

```
Onsuccess: function(){...}
```

Should it be:

```
onSuccess: function(){...}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working example: [JSFiddle Example](http://www.jsfiddle.net/subhaze/FfvXt/1/)

```
var msgCount = 0;

new Ajax.PeriodicalUpdater('chatMessages', '/echo/html/', {
    insertion: Insertion.Bottom,
    frequency: 2,
    decay: 2,
    onSuccess: function() {
        msgCount++;
        var response = '<div class="msg">Message '+msgCount+'</div>';
        response += '<div>'+bigLongString+'</div>';
        $('chatMessages').innerHTML += response;
        $('chatMessages').scrollTop = $('chatMessages').scrollHeight;
    }
});


var bigLongString = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum."
```

Comment: +1 for the example. You should have made your own answer instead of the comment. You deserved the green checkmark ;)

Comment: Thanks! Thought about that after I had commented, figured it was worth posting anyhow :)

Answer (score 1):

You have an assignment for `onsuccess`. What you need is either a reference to a function or inline function.

```
onsuccess: function(){$('chatMessages').scrollTop = $('chatMessages').scrollHeight;}
// or
onsuccess: my_callback_func
```

Comment: Check the docs, I don't know if `onsuccess` is a valid callback. I moved to jQuery earlier this year ;)

Comment: and @Ryley were both correct. There was a typo, it should be "onSuccess" and there should be no assignment for the onSuccess property just a callback function. Here is a link to a JSFiddle that is working correctly: http://www.jsfiddle.net/subhaze/FfvXt/

Comment: @subhaze Thanks for the clarification. I knew it wasn't `Onsuccess`, but should have checked the docs to provide a thorough answer.